# Is it possible for a single message to be given to multiply instance of the same subscription in gcloud PubSub

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a publisher that publishes messages to a particular **`topic (myTopic)`**, then on my PubSub I create a subscription **`name: myTopicSub`** to this **`topic (myTopic)`**, then I have a VM that runs a service that listeners on my subscription **`myTopicSub`**

THIS WORKS

MY PROBLEM IS: if there be a need to scale, and I add 5 more VM to handle more messages from my subscription...  is it possible for PubSub to send the same message to more than one VM...

Because I only need one VM to process the message once. Please I need help

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Pub/Sub offers at-least-once delivery. That means that a message can be delivered multiple times and in some cases, can be delivered to two different subscribers for the same subscription within a short period of time. That particular type of duplicate delivery is rare, but not impossible.

Subscribers have to be able to handle the delivery of duplicates and depending on their nature may handle it in different ways. For some, all actions are idempotent, so re-processing the same message has no ill effects. In other cases, the subscribers need to track which messages they have received and processed and if a message is a duplicate, just immediately ack the message instead of process it.

Comment: This is very helpful. to be sure do i need to set the messageOrdering to true in my publisher and my subscriber. am using node.js

Comment: The message ordering fields do not impact general duplicate delivery. This property is specific to a new feature in Cloud Pub/Sub that is in alpha.